# git clone --bare from ssh: objects folder empty

Tags: git, ssh, sshfs

I have a working directory on a server, which I can access either with interactive ssh or mounting my home with sshfs, and I would like to create a bare repository to start sharing it.

Doing

```
git clone --bare mount_point/path
```

and

```
git clone --bare ssh://user@server/path
```

give two different results. In particular, the main difference is in the objects folders. The first one has `00`, `0b`, ... subfolders and certain files in the `pack` subfolder. The second one instead has only `info` and `pack`, and the files in `pack` are different from the first case. As a consequence the sizes of the two cloned bare repos are different.

Though, on both I can successfully do either git log or, for instance, git diff.

Can anybody tell me what is happening? Could it be that git-clone over ssh compresses more the objects in the repository? Or am I losing information somewhere?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git optimizes cloned repository storage when it deals with repositories on the same volumes/same coputers. Look at `--no-hardlinks`, `--local`, etc options of `git clone --help`. Actually it's possible to force it make a "real copy" but usually you don't need to.

Update: Ok, no hardlinks. Before network transfer git packs objects, missing on the receiving side, and these packs are stored as they received, without unpacking. `git gc` does the same. `.git/objects/pack/` contains packed objects, as name suggests. To view contents of a particular pack file use `git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-<smth>.idx`. Check [this doc](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles) for a tutorial.

Comment: Actually this is not the case, because the working directory is on a different filesystem, so no hard links can be produced in this case. Also, by any chance do you know what the files inside objects/pack are?